# Displaying Dataverse images in PowerApps Portal

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

I'm trying to display the image attributes from Dataverse in the PowerApps Portal. I know the documentation says that this isn't officially supported I've seen a few unofficial guides like https://www.itaintboring.com/powerapps/lets-show-an-image-on-the-power-apps-portal-form-too/ which seems promissing.

My only problem with that solution is that it requires hard-coded URL's in the Portal which doesn't work for us as we have a CD pipeline with multiple environments.
Is there another way to do this? Or can I somehow query for the URL instead of hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so I'm posting it as answer.

1. you can retrieve the supporting image_url column value. The URL is stored in supporting imageColumn_url column.
   Full URL should be something like this {organization_URL}/image/download.aspx?entity={table_name}&attribute={column_name}&id={entityImageId}&timestamp={image_timestamp} and can be used as src in img tag.
2. in the img tag set data-entityimage to be the image column. On window load convert entity image to base64 source.

   ```
    <img data-entityimage="{{ imageColumn | join: ',' }}"  />
   ```

   function toBase64(str) {
   if (!str) return null;
   var uarr = new Uint8Array(str.split(',').map(function (x) { return parseInt(x); }));
   return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uarr));
   }

   ```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
       document.querySelectorAll('img[data-entityimage]').forEach(function (img) {
           var data = img.dataset && img.dataset.entityimage;
           var base64data = data ? toBase64(data) : null;
           if (base64data) {
              img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64data;
           }
      });
    });
   ```

With (1) you are retrieving full sized image, and with (2) the thumbnail that is stored in cds

Comment: Thanks for your input! However my problem with 1. is that it uses at different auth mechanism, so you are not guaranteed that the portal user will be authorized to see the image. I was hoping I could do something like 2. but for the full size as I definitely need the full size.